# Pandas : how to transform multi select column to index / column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe looking like that :

```
    2023-12-31          2024-01-31
   myvalue1   myvalue2  myvalue1    myvalue2
a   2          6          2           6
b   3          7          3           7
c   4          8          4           8
```

which can be created by :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'b', 'c'], data=
                   {'myvalue1':[2,3, 4], 'myvalue2':[6,7,8]})\
      .reindex(['myvalue1', 'myvalue2'] * 2, axis=1) \
        .set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['2023-12-31','2024-01-31'], ['myvalue1', 'myvalue2']]), axis=1)
```

How can I get the sum in each column in the following format :

```
                myvalue1      myvalue2  
2023-12-31         9           21
2024-01-31         9           21
```

Note that this is only the example where pair of columns are the same.

Thank you

Comment: Will you always have only those two columns with those dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) the rows and reshape with [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
out = df.sum().unstack()
```

Output:

```
            myvalue1  myvalue2
2023-12-31         9        21
2024-01-31         9        21
```